# Pro*C: How to implement Dynamic SQL for inserting data

Tags: sql, c, dynamic-sql

I'm new to pro*c coding and oracle. I need to insert data into various tables at run time depending on certain condition. Can anyone point me if I can implement the same using `dynamic sql method4`. Reading through the doc Im really confused.

Oracle doc gave some really nice examples but really confusing. Can anyone point me any simple documents or sites which it is easily understood or any sample code which is easy to understand.

I'm new to this forum, please forgive me if I'm asking too much. And google, I have been doing it this whole day and I'm lost.

Also, There are two types of implementations in method4, `ORACLE` & `ANSI`. ANSI seems to be simple method. any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple Pro*C snippet to execute Query immediately. Hope you've understood creating contexts.

```
int OraExecQuery(sql_context *sql_ctx, char *sql_query)
{
    /* Error Handling formalities */

    EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR GOTO OracleError;  

    EXEC SQL CONTEXT USE :sql_ctx;  

    EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_query; 

    EXEC SQL COMMIT; 

    return (/*Success*/);

OracleError:
    /* Handle errors using struct sqlca */
    return (/*Failure*/);
}
```

I too have read manuals from Oracle of necessary versions and did tryouts. On the other hand OCI is tougher to grasp.